# Fire an event when Selenium ChromeDriver's URL changes

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, driver

I am using **Selenium** `ChromeDriver` and I need to handle the event of an arbitrary URL change coming from the displayed browser head (basically, all those navigations caused by the end-user clicking on the page).

In .NET default `WebBrowser` control we can make use of`WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted`, which selenium's browsers don't have.

For example:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.UrlChanged += OnUrlChanged; // the event I need

void OnUrlChanged(){
    //handle any url change here caused by the user navigating on the browser.
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @JeffC excuse me, but there's nothing to share out of my research simply because I found nothing regarding the matter, that's why I am asking the community on how to achieve my goal

Answer (score 0):

I found a "nasty" solution which is `WebDriverWait`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6));

wait.Until(driver => driver.Url.Contains("urlpart"));

//code to be executed when the url will contain urlpart
```

However, this won't solve the needing of having an event that fires whenever the page changes, especially because the above method is too much of procedural coding.